# How to run AngularJS material design using node

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, material-design

I just started learning the AngularJS material design. Well, it's quite interesting but i still dont know how to run using Node. Below is my app structure -

[image]

All i know to test my app is by using `serve` in cmd for my project directory and test it by `localhost`. My question is can this be tested like other Node projects? Also i need some how to host this app.

When i try to open the index.html directly, the website looks like below -

[image]

All files linked correctly but still error shown in console.

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: AngularJS is a client side library. NodeJS is irrelevant, no?

Comment: Yes, but this material design is little different. It uses node_modules and when i try to open the index.html, the material design is not applied.

Comment: looks like angular does not run on the page. what do you have in the browser console?

Comment: But i tried running through `serve` and it works perfectly on Chrome as i wanted

Comment: I've just started working on a MEAN app (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node). I started by downloading a working scaffold from meanjs.org. It works out of the box. The meanjs.org stuff is full of best practices for organising code for node and angular, so I would recommend starting there. However don't expect to start work on some marvellous app immediately. I'd advise you to learn as much as you can from what they have done before trying to programme in earnest. There's Grunt, Bower, Jade, ecc. all explained and lots more.

Comment: I accept your advice. I used to learn by doing which i feel more comfortable and its just a static app.

Comment: @RaghavMac the fact is that it does not work now, and I am trying to help by suggesting that you look at the console and check for any errors.

Comment: Sorry, i should have checked in console first. But i don't know why it showing error for all the file when it is linked correctly.

Comment: what errors do you see? could you post here?

Comment: looks like your links use `file://` schema. you need to use `http://`. is your html file served by node server, or are you opening it from local drive directly?

Comment: I have some different errors(post edited) and i have the js files inside my project folders.

Comment: please see my previous comment

Comment: Actually it uses node. But what i did now is opened the index.html from local drive like a normal AngularJS app.

Comment: @akonsu Thanks for the previous comment, got an idea from it and copied the required js and css files to my projects and done. It works